# How can find a sample api from internet for list of category and list of subCategory. subCategory will be based on category

Tags: java, android, api

I need the sample Api to integrate in my android application. If any one provide me the link it will be help full for me. Based on the api I will able to create the model classes also and will able to show the list in recyclerView.

Comment: Need more info here. Do you need an endpoint which should give you your sample response? Or you just need to formulate sample response? Is it Json endpoint you are expecting.

Comment: Yes need an endpoint which should give sample response and expecting a json endpoint - @Knu8

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There might be multiple solutions to what you want to do.

https://www.mockaroo.com/ is something I use to generate test data. It has the flexibility to generate 1000s of rows of data and also in many formats e.g. Json, csv.

If you want to get that data via an endpoint then you can use **postman** on your local.

I am also sure that there are many websites that will provide the test Json data you want and serve it via an endpoint. example https://mocki.io/fake-json-api

Comment: OP is asking for recommendations to software, probably downvoted for accommodating that, beyond that they most likely don't want mocks